# Segfault in c++ stl map find due to static variable cleanup during process exit

Tags: c++, stl, fork, mutex, segmentation-fault

I do operations on an STL map in the following functions, all of which are protected by a mutex:-

```
static std::mutex track_active_lock_mtx;
typedef intrusive_ptr<WatchCtxInternal> WatchCtxInternal_h;
static std::map<WatchCtxInternal*, WatchCtxInternal_h> actives;
void* get_ptr(WatchCtxInternal_h ctx) 
{
    unique_lock<mutex> trackActiveLock(track_active_lock_mtx);
    if(actives.find(ctx.get()) == actives.end()) {
        actives.insert(make_pair(ctx.get(), ctx));
    }    
    trackActiveLock.unlock();
    return ctx.get();
}

void genericWatcher(void *watcherCtx)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> trackActiveLock(track_active_lock_mtx);
    auto it = actives.find((WatchCtxInternal*)watcherCtx);
    if (it == actives.end()) {          
        return;
    }
    //do unrelated stuff
    actives.erase(it);
}
```

I got a segmentation fault in the first function:-

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  _M_lower_bound (this=<optimized out>, __k=<optimized out>, __y=0xf31256e8, __x=0x65687465) at /volume/evo/files/opt/poky/1.8.2-4/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1261
1261            if (!_M_impl._M_key_compare(_S_key(__x), __k))
(gdb) bt
#0  _M_lower_bound (this=<optimized out>, __k=<optimized out>, __y=0xf31256e8, __x=0x65687465) at /volume/evo/files/opt/poky/1.8.2-4/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1261
#1  find (__k=<optimized out>, this=0xf6ac8e2c <actives>) at /volume/evo/files/opt/poky/1.8.2-4/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1913
#2  find (__x=<optimized out>, this=0xf6ac8e2c <actives>) at /volume/evo/files/opt/poky/1.8.2-4/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_map.h:860
#3  get_ptr (ctx=...) 
(gdb)fr 3
(gdb) p ctx
$4 = {px = 0xf3124d30}
```

EDIT: I managed to get a stack trace using the Memcheck tool. What is happening is that the static map gets cleaned up as part of the process exit, but a callback to genericWatcher is occurring in the  other thread before completely exiting:-

main.cpp

```
static void thread1(void *arg) {
    //call genericWatcher repeatedly
}

int main() {
    if(fork() == 0) {
       pthread_create(..., thread1,..)
       //call get_ptr() repeatedly
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this? I could allocate a singleton that holds the actives map, but I try to avoid using singletons

Comment: couldn't reproduce with current unit test

Comment: Your example code is supposed to be minimal but complete! Nobody can reproduce your issues like that.

Comment: These functions got executed a couple hundred times in some sequence before the crash occured, it is hard to put that information here. What I'm asking is if there is any scope for corruption in spite of the locking scheme in place

Comment: Not that it should matter, but why are you doing explicitly `trackActiveLock.unlock();`? It will get automatically unlocked at return anyway...

Comment: just an optimization, i like keeping my critical sections small

Answer (score 0):

The most likely point of failure is the `erase` call in your `release` callback because it's the only access point to your map that hasn't got any guarding mechanism. Are you sure at that point that your `WatchCtx` is part of the map's keys? If not, it sounds possible that the insert is already letting go. 
But, like Velkan already said, valgrind (or your debugger of choice) will give you certainty.

Comment: Isn't it protected by the unique_lock? Maybe I misunderstood how that works

Comment: @Bug Killer the lock protects the map from multiple access at the same time. It doesn't protect it from the key you give it not being in the map to begin with (for example, if it never was added properly). I don't know the program's context and calling constraints sufficiently to verify or falsify that. If you check the key using `find` before your call to `erase` there and the error stops occurring, I'd take a look at your insertion routines or the way you determine which `WatchCtx` you're removing when.

Comment: I think calling erase with a  non-existent key is safe: [695754]

Comment: @Bug Killer Thanks. Wow, I DO need to tell someone to reconsider their compiler.